# New line issue & Image need to pass in the cell for smartsheet API

Tags: php, smartsheet-api, drupal-9, smartsheet-api-1.1

we are passing the comment section with a rich-text editor which includes the image and paragraph type as the inputs to the smartsheet API cell. But i have the following error

```
{
"errorCode" : 1008,
"message" : "Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Field \"value\" was 
not parsable. Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using 
backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: 
java.io.PushbackInputStream@ae5bd59; line: 23, column: 337].",
"refId" : "3g83d4"
}
```

This is something with the New line `"\"` and CR `"\r"`. But I tried with PHP Functions like `str_replace`, `nl2br` and `Preg_replace` but nothing reflected in the Smartsheet API cell.

```
                $curl = curl_init();
           curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
           CURLOPT_URL => 'API URL',
           CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
           CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
           CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
           CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
           CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
           CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
           CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
           CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'[
            {
                "toBottom": true,
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "columnId": 3894513397196676,
                        "value": "'.$body.'"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnId": 6797054443317124,
                        "value": "Link",
                        "hyperlink": {
                            "url": "'.$current_url.'"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "columnId": 1167554909104004,
                        "value": "Assigned"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Values',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
          ),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Can you please help us with where I missed the issue?

Comment: If you could share some code and sample data, that would make it a lot easier to help debug the issue.

Comment: Hi @MatthewSetter
Thanks for your Comment. Code Added
Here is the problem with "body" variable

Comment: If you're able to update your post to show the full JSON body that's being sent to the Smartsheet API, I could probably provide some feedback for you. But without knowing the value of `'.$body.'` and `'.$current_url.'` it's hard to guess what's causing this issue.

Comment: @KimBrandl said it well. It's impossible to debug fully without that information, or something closely approximating it, if the information is sensitive, private, or confidential.

Comment: json_encode($comment_body, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)

Solution for this issue